# Whole number or decimal number

Tags: php

I'm looking for a function that tests to see if an integer is a whole number. 
So far I've got this:

```
if (is_numeric($answer3)) {
    echo "Is triangular\n";
} else {
    echo "Is not triangular\n";
}
```

But this always returns "Is triangular", even when $answer3 is a decimal.

How can I test an integer to see if it has a decimal?

Comment: Just a note, PHP is extremely flexible with strings and numbers (and strings that look like numbers).  Many consider it **too** flexible.  If this is of any sort of importance, I cannot stress enough the need to thoroughly test your script.

Comment: Just to be clear: an integer is always a whole number. What you probably mean is to check whether a "string" or "float" has a "fractional part" or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[is_numeric](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) will return true for floats too, considering floats are numeric

> Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist
> of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and
> optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value.
> Hexadecimal notation (0xFF) is allowed too but only without sign,
> decimal and exponential part.

You can try is_float(), but if the input is a string it wont work.

```
var_dump( is_float( '23.5' ) ); // return false
```

So if you are dealing with something that is a string representation of a number then just look for a `.`

```
if ( strpos( $answer3, '.' ) === false )
```

You can add is_numeric if you need to

```
// Make sure its numeric and has no decimal point
if ( is_numeric( $answer3 ) && strpos( $answer3, '.' ) === false )
```

Comment: What about scientific notation? 1e-2 passes the check

Answer (score 16):

Should `10.0` be considered as an integer or a float? If integer, you're looking for [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php):

```
if (fmod($number, 1) == 0) // $number DOES NOT have a significant decimal part
{
    // is whole number
}
```

Otherwise, [`is_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) suffices.

---

**EDIT:** Another way to check for insignificant decimal part would be:

```
if (round($number, 0) == $number)
{
    // is whole number
}
```

Comment: The 2nd parameter for `round()` is not needed : `if (round($number) == $number)` will work well

Answer (score 4):

- `is_int` if you also need it to be of the type integer,
- `ctype_digit` if you are testing strings,
- `filter_var($input,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` for all.

And search the manual

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several answers (from other pages as well), but what worked best in my case is this:

```
$number = floatval($number);
if ($number == round($number)) {
    // Number does not have decimals (or .00000)
}else{
    // Number does have decimals
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is most elegant solution:

```
if ( $answer3 != (int) ( $answer3 ) ) {
```

Comment: This function will give false positives for the following values: `array()`, `'0x12foo'`,`'0xfe'`,`'8e2bottles'`.

Answer (score 1):

If $answer3 isn't a string, you can try using:

```
is_float()
```

to see if is a floating point value, rather than just a numeric value.

Comment: If the input is a floating point number, it won't fail... only if you pass a string to is_float.  In the OP's text above it isn't clear what $answer3 is.  Downvote is a bit harsh but I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Don't take it personal, I just don't think float checking is enough here. A triangular number is any number of the form `(n * (n + 1)) / 2`. If I give you a float value such as `10.000` or `15.000`, neither `is_float()` or `is_int()` will correctly address the OP needs.

Comment: Not taking it personally :)  It just looked like to me that the OP wanted a way to check for floating point numbers. I ignored the triangular part because OP didn't specifically ask for it, just "How can I test an integer to see if it has a decimal?"

Comment: I've already coded the test for a triangular number, if it isn't a triangular at the end of the maths it will return with a decimal place.

Comment: If $answer3 is the result of your math to check for a triangular number then I'm guessing it's not a string, therefore you can use is_float() to check if it has a decimal place.  There are several answers here which tell you that, please mark one as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

This function does the job for 99% of the time for every input you throw in:

```
function($number) {
    (float)(int)$number == (float)$number;
}
```

Note: Strict comparison is not really necessary here, because when casting to (float) both are always the same type.

Inspired by [this article about PHP insanity](http://www.maweki.de/wp/2012/11/php-comparison-explained/) when comparing values, I ran a little test for the following inputs:

**As expected**

These values **do not** have a fractional part:

```
1.0  // TRUE
'1.0'  // TRUE
true  // TRUE
false  // TRUE
'true'  // TRUE
'false'  // TRUE
10e3  // TRUE
0123  // TRUE
null  // TRUE
'test'  // TRUE
1  // TRUE
0  // TRUE
1.2e3  // TRUE
0xfe  // TRUE
0b0  // TRUE
0b1  // TRUE
b0  // TRUE
b1  // TRUE
-0xfe  // TRUE
''  // TRUE
'8bottles'  // TRUE
'8.0bottles'  // TRUE
'0foo'  // TRUE
array()  // TRUE
'0x12foo'  // TRUE
'0123'  // TRUE
'0xfe'  // TRUE
new Object // TRUE
```

These values **do** have a fractional part:

```
'1.1' // FALSE
1.1 // FALSE
10e-3 // FALSE
.9 // FALSE
0.9 // FALSE
.1 // FALSE
0.1 // FALSE
0123.2 // FALSE
7E-10 // FALSE
1.2e-3 // FALSE
```

**Not expected:**

```
'8e2bottles' // FALSE
```

As explained in the article, this value will do crazy stuff and will also fail in my function. It's because casting to `int` and `float` gives a total different value. So be prepared!

```
(int)'8e2bottles' // 8
(float)'8e2bottles' // 800.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked all the answers and there were few trying to check for the floating part. That's the correct way to do, except that it's not a good idea to compare floating point numbers using equal sign. Best solution would be:

```
function isIntegerNumber($number){
  $floor = floor($number);
  $fract = abs($number - $floor);
  return is_numeric($number) && $fract < 1e-16;
}

echo var_export(isIntegerNumber("10X"), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber("3.0001"), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber("-23.0001"), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber(-10.01), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber("3.00"), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber("-23.00"), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber(-10.00), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber(5), true).PHP_EOL;
echo var_export(isIntegerNumber(-5), true).PHP_EOL;
$tricky = (0.1+0.7)*10.0;
echo "now something a bit tricky: ".PHP_EOL;
echo "(0.1+0.7)*10.0 = ".var_export($tricky, true) .' (type: "'.gettype($tricky).'")'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'is it int: '.var_export(isIntegerNumber($tricky), true).PHP_EOL;
echo 'is it 8: '.var_export($tricky == 8, true).PHP_EOL;
```

result:

```
false
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
true
now something a bit tricky: 
(0.1+0.7)*10.0 = 7.9999999999999991 (type: "double")
is it int: false
is it 8: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fully new in this, but I figure it out that best way to check if a number is float or integer in PHP is by simple check:

```
if ($number == round($number)) { } else { }
```

If it's truly a integer it will be equal.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if(!is_numeric($nabtron) || $nabtron != floor($nabtron) || $nabtron < 0){
    echo "it's not numeric or is a float or a negative number";
}
```

or in case you need positive results:

```
if(is_numeric($nabtron) && $nabtron == floor($nabtron) &&  $nabtron < 0){
    echo "it's numeric and not a float and is zero or positive number";
}
```